# Using Bluez/Linux, can I run a daemon broadcasting BLE ibeacons and be connectable using RFCOMM simultaneously?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, rfcomm

As stated in the title, can both be ran simultaneously or is a second adapter required?  For example, can one adapter run both BLE and BT classic at the same time - the BLE beacon broadcasts the MAC for opportunistic clients to connect to using RFCOMM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a common CSR 4.0 Dongle or Ampac AP6212 (which purportedly uses the same Broadcom chip as the RPI3) then this is possible - they are "dual-stack".

Given this, the typical USB CSR chips have a hard limit of two connected RFCOMM clients and the Ampac, 8 or maybe more (tested for sure 8).